# how to iterate through an array of strings so that each value is matched with every other 1 once and only once

Tags: java, loops

Say I have an string array with 5 elements, I want to loop through the array so that I have element [0] and element [1] through element [0] and element [4].

I then want to start at element[1] and do the same and again for every element but discarding any matching groupings.

e.g `arr[] {a,b,c,d,e}`

`(a-b),(a-c),(a-d),(a-e)`

then

`(b-c),(b,d),(b,e)`

then

`(c-d),),(c-e)`

then

`(d-e)`

Thanks

Comment: These are actually called [_k-subsets combinations_](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Combination.html) (combinations of k elements from the set `{a,b,c,d,e}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work for you:

```
List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        result.add(new String[]{arr[i], arr[j]});
    }
}
```

The "collect" part where you add a string array to the list (i.e. `result.add(...)`) can obviously be replaced with whatever you need for your code. The main thing here is that you find your "pair" using `arr[i]` and `arr[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `5`'s with the length of your array:

```
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    for (j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
        // arr[i] & arr[j]
```

Comment: why replace .length with 5 if you don't mind me asking? I know It looks cleaner.

Comment: So that it will still work if you change the length of `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] strings = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
    int j = 0;
    while (j < strings.length){
        int k = j + 1;
        while (k < strings.length){
            // if String array element j does not match with String array element k, do something like print the combiations or whatever you choose.
            if (!(strings[j].equals(strings[k]))) System.out.println("(" + strings[j] + "," + strings[k] + ")");
            k = k + 1;
        }
        j = j + 1;
    }
```